# Cloud Data Fusion Instance Won't Delete

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I have tried to delete a cloud data fusion instance.  The console has said the instance is deleting for over a few days now.  Even though I don't have an actual pipeline running it is accumulating charges ~$40/day.  When I try to delete the instance stuck on delete I get an error saying deletion of  failed.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of that error?
Also, could you share the project id or instance name?

Comment: Does the error persist if you try to delete the instance again?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when i mistakenly removed some of the Service Accounts. I'm unable to recall which SA. I used this to undelete the SA:

```
$ gcloud beta iam service-accounts undelete __ACCOUNT_ID__
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Data Fusion(DF) was in a state of deletion for days.

There is an option for update of DF from the console. When I tried to 'update' the instance went back to running state. After that the deletion was successful.

[I hope this can help someone.]